# Flip Print Job Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfpdf, cfprint

I need help flipping a print job in ColdFusion. It is printing upside down. I can change this setting manually in the printer options (form control panel) but how can I do it in coldfusion?

```
<cfprint type="pdf" source="#ExpandPath('includes/assets/#FORM.MRN#_#FORM.CSN#.pdf')#" attributeStruct="#aset#">
```

I tried the orientation "reverse-portrait" and it did not work as intended.

Comment: have you tried rotating the paper in your printer?

Comment: Or after the document is printed.  I'm having trouble visualizing the problem.

Comment: The problem is, it is a print job for a label printer. Flipping the labels does not work. These labels have an upper label and lower label (basically one label but split and perforated in two). The information is printing on the lower label. When I change the settings manually for the label printer to rotate 180, it prints properly on the upper label.

Comment: One of my duties involves label printing using Loftware.  In that case, this situation is handled by making the label files themselves inverted.  Maybe the answer lies in the production of your pdf file itself instead of when you try to print it.  Or is that what the "reverse-portrait" orientation is all about?

Comment: Right so the "production" of the label is all done in coldfusion. We send commands to pull info from a SQL db such as name, address etc. So, I am not sure we can invert anything there. I am trying to invert just prior to printing and that is failing, or, not working.

Comment: An approach might be to use cfpdf to convert your document to an image.  Then use cfimage to rotate it 180 degrees.  Then print the image.